# Wait for controller to load in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

On a certain page (page1.html) of my Ionic app, I link to a new page, let's say page2.html .
The controller of page2.html takes some arrays (with +1000 people in it), puts the arrays together, sorts it alphabetically and removes duplicates. This proces takes a long time, so when I click the button on page1.html, nothing seems to happen. After 5-7 seconds, the new page is loaded and the transition between the two pages is shown.
Is there a way to prevent this? For example, I was thinking about showing a loading spinner when I click the button, and to remove it when the controller of page2 has finished sorting the array

```
$scope.showloading = function(){

    $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading...',
        template: "<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><br />Loading...",
        showBackdrop: true,
        showDelay: 0
    });
    window.location="page2.html";

};
```

But the spinner is only shown AFTER the loading is done... Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: can you give some codepen of actual problem.

Comment: Is your controller's loading process synchronous?

Comment: Your showLoading function is probably being called after all the loading and sorting. Is that taking place in a resolve?

Comment: @Shaun I guess that's probably the case, but how can I make sure the loading is called first?

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code to say for sure, but I imagine you are making an $http call to get the array of "1,000+ people in it"...and if so, calling $ionicLoading.show before that should do the trick. You'd then call something like $ionicLoading.hide in the success callback (again I'm guessing, since I don't know what your code looks like).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not using a http call on that page. On the very first page of the app (when the user "lands") a call is made, which provides info off all sorts of things (reason: all info should be available offline once 1 call succeeded) . The array is stored and on every page I use the info I need. That's not a problem on all other pages, because the arrays are (and always will be) much smaller.